# Override/extend constructor behavior

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extend a class from a third party module

```js
declare module 'pixi.js' {
    interface DisplayObject {
        updatables: Set<Updatable>
        update(delta: number): void
    }
}

DisplayObject.prototype.updatables = new Set()

DisplayObject.prototype.update = function (delta: number) {
    this.updatables.forEach(u => u.update(delta))
    // ...
}
```

This correctly adds an `update` method to all DisplayObjects and child classes, but the `updatable` set is shared, ie each instance does not have its own array. I need a `new Set()` for each instance.

Is there a way to achieve this?

UPDATE - some clarifications:
many of the 3rd-party module classes depend **by extension** on DisplayObject. The interface of all child classes is updated correctly via the TypeScript interface merge. The update method is also successfully injected via prototype just like the updatables set (but only one, shared by all instances instead one per instance).

UPDATE 2 - I found a solution using lazy loading with get/set which instantiates the Set of updatables on first access. It works, but it seems a bit hacky/overkill.

Comment: Is there some reason you *have* to monkeypatch it instead of `class MyDisplayObject extends DisplayObject` or even better `class DisplayObjectWrapper { private displayObject: DisplayObject }`?

Comment: @JaredSmith Because many classes of the third-party module depend (by extension) directly on DisplayObject. The problem is precisely how to replace or modify this class without break anything. I really need all derived classes to have those members as well.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily hold: any 3rd party function that takes an instance of that class will take a subclass instance. Even if you for some reason can't subclass the additional functionality would be unknown to the 3rd party code, only your code could use it, and you can do anything you want in your own code including associating data with specific instances by using them as keys in a WeakMap. Can you be more specific about your use case here? Because the short answer to your question is **no**, you can't monkey patch a class constructor after the fact.

Comment: @JaredSmith This is precisely one of the most common ways to extend behaviors thanks to typescript's interface fusion. Thanks to this, the child classes (when I use them) do know the new members of their parent class. It works like a shot for behaviors (ie methods), but so far I've never dealt with per instance properties.

Comment: @UKX does the following work for you? (I needed to ts-ignore disallowed class assignment) https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=24#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oA8Bc0B2ArgLYBGApgE4Dc60w8eEALhQcE-BQBQCUKtGJgAsAlhAB0maAF5oARhoYAvhlRLUAeg3QAggAc9FeGGBD5uAKIBlaAAUjmAJ6p6jJnQbNW7ABJg8ACYglDL8GK5ebExcTGAUAOZkTLj+jgA00HHxECl4jnxoGOGe7hRJoXhkAO7QsQlJXOJNWRA8ikVlTJKhAMztGJ0EFHjQne1KaWo0mhoAAkwQALQi8XicZKgISLKVNfbwTlxbGREsUX6BwRRtqDO6BkYmZgBMuABmBHjsIgx3p9DwEABLahLY0LTQLTzJYrNZlO4g2QfL5MH54Xj8CFFf6dCrVAFAra8cHaIqjJLdWR9O5kwbDclMEnQdS3f5vRB4mpEm4RQFkcQgeDxLjs+BtIA

Comment: @Lesiak For both approaches: if I could reassign Foo, there wouldn't even be a need for a proxy, a child class would work. The problem is that I can't just make Foo = whatever (proxy, function, child class...) and have its child classes somehow inherit/use this new assignment. Or I can? It is my main doubt.

Comment: You can assign the proxy to the child class prototype `Child.__proto__ = Foo;`
Obviously this is hacky and not scalable if there are a lot of child classes.

Comment: @Lesiak yes, I know. Effectively I want to avoid having to modify the ```__proto__``` in all child classes. If that were a possibility, I can replace the parent class directly with a subclass instead a Proxy. I'm looking for a way around this scalability problem (monkey patching is the best words to describe what I want to do)

Comment: @UXK this is for pixi so I'm assuming? it's for a game. Everything that you're doing (e.g. modifying prototypes) can have deleterious effects on performance in a way that a simple subclass does not. Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean it's good for your use case, which is *again* why I asked you to share more about what you're *actually* trying to accomplish here.  In any case, it looks like you found a solution your satisfied with, so good deal.

Comment: @JaredSmith thanks but wrong assumption =P. Pixi is not a game engine It's just a rendering system that's also very agnostic, my question is more general and my case is not a game either. I think adding something that wasn't previously in a class or its children shouldn't make any difference beyond possible conflicts with future versions or field serialization. If you think that is wrong, I would sincerely appreciate it if you share your knowledge with an answer, explaining possible risks even if it is not a positive answer to my problem.

Comment: @UXK if it's not a game you're *probably* fine. It mostly depends on how many/often you're creating these objects: for n objects for some value of n it doesn't matter if you trigger a de-opt in the JIT by modifying a prototype. If you're creating thousands or tens of thousands (or more) of these objects it could bite you.